# React Native - useState hook to update array within an object of arrays

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

How do I use `useState` hook to update an array within an array of objects that's dependent on an array index?

end goal data:

```
foodData = [
  {
    foodId: 'fdsafsdafsa',
    fruitsArray: ['banana', 'orange']
  },
  {
    foodId: '234243fdsfdsafsasdf343432afsdafsa',
    fruitsArray: ['apple']
  },
  {
    foodId: 'fdsafsdafsa',
    fruitsArray: ['strawberry', 'orange']
  },
]
```

I have a function with arguments, `(fruits, fruitIndex, foodIndex, foodId)`

```
const logFruitsIntoFoodData = (fruits, fruitIndex, foodIndex, foodId) => {
  // update state here...


  const foodToUpdate = {...foodData};

  foodToUpdate[foodIndex] = {
    ...foodData[foodIndex],

    // This gets overwritten, 
    // how do I continue to add or 
    // update the fruit based on fruit index? 
    ['fruitsArray']: fruits, 
  };


}
```

I'm trying to update/add fruits into the **fruitsArray** so when the function gets invoked, it'll insert the proper fruits into **foodData**, or it'll update it, depending on what the **fruitIndex** is.

Should I be using two separate `useState`:

```
const [foodData, setFoodData]= useState([]);
const [fruitsArray, setFruitsArray] = useState([]);
```

where I should get the array of fruits first, then add it into foodData, or can I just have 1 useState to deal with everything?

Comment: So in that function, do you want to find the relevant `foodId` / `foodIndex` from your array (seems to me you can use either) and then modify the `fruitsArray` index specified in `fruitIndex`? And do you want to add the specified `fruits` to the existing ones? Is `fruits` an array of multiple fruits? If so then are you adding/replacing them all starting from `fruitIndex`, or what's the intention?

Comment: @James in the function, I'm trying to use `fruits` (which is a single value argument) to insert (or update) into `fruitsArray`. I was thinking that `fruitIndex` can help figure out which index is in the array to update the fruit (let's assume that each fruit goes into a specific order of the array. The purpose for `foodIndex` - is supposed to be used to ensure that the value of the `fruits` is going to the correct `foodId`. I hope this makes more sense?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'd use an array, since you have `foodId`, meaning you could easily convert foodData into an object. I'd say if you're using an array then use the index. If you want to use `foodId` to identify the item you're updating, then just make `foodData` an object.

It's a little bit cumbersome but this is what I think you're trying to do:

```
const logFruitsIntoFoodData = (fruit, fruitIndex, foodIndex) => {
  // isolate the food you're updating and clone it

  const foodToUpdate = { ...foodData[foodIndex] };

  // replace fruit in the specified index...

  foodToUpdate.fruitsArray.splice(fruitIndex, 1, fruit);

  // clone existing state

  const newFoodDataState = [...foodData];

  // replace the item in the specified

  newFoodDataState.splice(foodIndex, 1, foodToUpdate);

  // set new state

  setFoodData(newFoodDataState);
};
```

I'm not 100% sure this is what you meant. Let me know and I can modify accordingly!

Comment: I get a splice undefined. I think its because `fruitsArray` doesn't exist yet. The data I'm creating doesn't exist yet. The `foodData` is just an illustration of what the data could look like.

Comment: I updated my question in the function. What I was trying to do is displayed there. The issue I was getting at is how do I update `fruitsArray` without getting overwritten each time the function gets invoked?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work when I did it like this:

```
const [foodData, setFoodData]= useState([]);

const logFruitsIntoFoodData = (fruits, fruitIndex, foodIndex, foodId) => {

  // checks if the index exists in the array.

  if (!foodData[foodIndex]) {
    foodData[foodIndex] = {
      foodId,
      fruitsArray: [],
    };
    setFoodData({...foodData});
  }

  // now I can insert fruits depending on the fruitIndex
  foodId[foodIndex].fruitsArray[fruitIndex] = fruits;

}
```

Not sure if this is the best method, but it works. If anyone has a better way, I'd love to hear it!